# Polynomial interpolation of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, interpolation

Let $f\in A(\Omega)$ be an analytic function on a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ and let $a_0,a_1\cdots a_m\in \omega\Subset \Omega$ where $\omega$ is a smooth open set compactly contained in $\Omega$. Show that $$p(z) =  f(z)- \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\partial \omega}\prod_{j=0}^{m}\left(\frac{z-a_j}{\zeta-a_j}\right)\frac{f(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta-z}$$

is the unique polynomial of degree at most m that interpolates $f$ at $a_0,a_1\cdots a_m\in \omega $ i.e such that $f(a_j)=P(a_j)$, $j=0,1,\dots ,m .$

My problem is that I am not able to prove that the above defined  $P(z)$ is a polynomial. 
But the fact $f(a_j)=P(a_j)$ follows immediately from Cauchy formula.

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298399/analytic-function-and-the-lagrange-interpolating-polynomial/, specifically from the tag $(1)$ onwards … and see if it helps ... in a way, it's a duplicate.